# Why do I need an instance of Odbc reader, but now Odbc connection?

Tags: .net, odbc, c++-cli

On the class level, I have declared:

```
System::Data::Odbc::OdbcConnection conn;
System::Data::Odbc::OdbcDataReader datareader; //doesnt work
System::Data::Odbc::OdbcDataReader^  datareader; //works
```

However, the `dataReader` has to be declared as `OdbcDataReader^`. I dont understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `OdbcConnection conn;` you are instantiating a connection object directly (on the stack). Not sure if that is a good idea but it is possible.

You cannot do that with a `OdbcDataReader datareader;` because that class only has hidden (private/internal) constructors. That is by design, you are not supposed to create DataReaders directly but instead get them from a call to  `ExecuteReader()`. And ExecuteReader returns `OdbcDataReader^` . See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhcdfhz9.aspx).

Comment: I need to instantionate connection directly because many methods share it and its also passed to other classes as parameter.

Comment: Petr, if you need to share the connection then you probably _do_ want a reference (managed pointer).

Comment: whilst the second para of this answer is helpful, the first is factually incorrect - Despite syntactic appearances, the instance is not created on the stack, it's still on the managed heap; it's just that it is deterministically disposed when the scope ends.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know C# and C++ but not the CLI stuff. Feel free to edit, or copy paste to your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but here goes:

Connection and DataReader classes come in pairs on the .NET Framework, depending on the database technology used. So you have `OdbcConnection` and `OdbcDataReader`, also `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader`, etc. You have always to use them in pairs. Note anyway that all of these implement the common interfaces `IDataConnection` and `IDataReader`.

**EDIT**. Fine, I completely misunderstood the question. :-/

I usually use C#, not C++, but I think that it is because you can directly create a new instance of `OdbcConnection`, but as for the `OdbcDataReader`, you need to obtain an instance by executing the `ExecuteReader` method on the corresponding `OdbcCommand`. ExecuteReader returns a pointer to a new OdbcDataReader object.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is why I dont need use handle with odbcconnection, while I have to useOdbcDataReader^?